# Speed up POST request, if specified domain is known to be on the same computer

Tags: php, networking, post, http-headers, localhost

I have two websites running on one computer. Both run on php.

First one often makes POST requests to the second. Is there any way to speed requests up, by skipping some steps, like dns resolving?

Is it possible to skip networking alltogether, while still getting php to interpret it as POST request? And without changing source code of the second website, which recieves this request?

Comment: None of those things will make any significant difference.

Comment: By "insignificant" you are speaking in terms of milli or microseconds? If in terms of milliseconds, I'm willing to look for it.

Comment: Probably none at all, since the extra overhead of having to choose to use these faster paths will completely erase the benefits of the faster paths.

Comment: I know beforehand that script can use faster path, and able to hardcode it (yup, I know that this is a bad practice).

Comment: Well then you can hard code in the IP address instead of the domain name. But it still is very unlikely to make a measurable difference. If you have performance issues, work on the things that are taking time now.

Comment: Maybe the question was not properly voiced. Websites are on the same computer. IP address would be 127.0.0.1. Invoking network interface is somewhat time-consuming, I suppose. And futile, because request still goes to the same computer. I want to try to skip this.

Comment: A computer doesn't use a network interface to talk to itself. How could it? What would send the packets back to it?

Comment: Really? Maybe I'm missing some fundamental knowledge here, will try to catch up. And script is able to perform HTTP request with POST data without using network?

Comment: How could it use the network? It's not talking to anything on the network. If it sent the data over the network, what would send it back to it?

Comment: It may not use the physical network (i.e. go out on the wire) but it would still use the network/TCP stack when using 127.0.0.1 (via the virtual Loopback interface).  I doubt there's any way to avoid that because websites, by definition, are accessed via network/TCP connections (even locally).

Comment: You could put both the sites as 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, that would at least skip the DNS lookup.

Comment: Thank you, everybody, I have my answer now. 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file is the best I can do. It will skip dns lookup, and in some cases prevent even one hop to the closest node and back. This hop was yje thing causing some slowdown on my sistem. @GordonM answer the question, if you want, I will mark it as correct answer.

Comment: What hop? @DavidSchwartz has already told you several times there isn't one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put both the sites as 127.0.0.1 in the hosts file, that would at least skip the DNS lookup.  I don't think you could do much better than that though.